# Return 2 output parameters from a C# function

Tags: c#

I'm using output parameters to get values from my database from a stored procedure and that works fine.

But, here is the C# code:

```
public string stAnswer(int idFirst, int idSecond)
{
    try
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(stConexion);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("spConsultarPreguntas", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id_First", idFirst));
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id_Second", idSecond));

        sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
        sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@First_A";
        sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        sqlParameter.Size = 50;
        sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        sqlParameter1 = new SqlParameter();
        sqlParameter1.ParameterName = "@Second_A";
        sqlParameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        sqlParameter1.Size = 50;
        sqlParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter1);

        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return sqlParameter.Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm returning `sqlParameter` value, but I have two parameters, how can I return two values? In this case `sqlParameter` and `sqlParameter1`.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Add them to an array and make your method return array of string Maybe

Comment: Or, result= result1+","+result2 then return result

Comment: @burg.developer Those are both very hacky ways to handle this when we have Tuple classes, value tuples, out parameters, or just creating a custom class to hold the outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C# Tuple class to return multiple values from a function

```
public Tuple<string,string> stAnswer(int idFirst, int idSecond)
{
try
{
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(stConexion);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("spConsultarPreguntas", sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id_First", idFirst));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id_Second", idSecond));

    sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
    sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@First_A";
    sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    sqlParameter.Size = 50;
    sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    sqlParameter1 = new SqlParameter();
    sqlParameter1.ParameterName = "@Second_A";
    sqlParameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    sqlParameter1.Size = 50;
    sqlParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter1);

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return Tuple.Create(sqlParameter.Value.ToString(),sqlParameter1.Value.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
}
```

you can call it like a normal function

```
 var tpl=stAnswer(idFirst,idSecond);
```

and can get the values in the order you returned from tuple
     var str1=tpl.Item1;
     var str2=tpl.Item2;

but more better approach will be to use named Tuple which was added in C# 7

```
 public(string perameter1,string parameter2)stAnswer(int idFirst, int idSecond)
 { 
   parameter1=sqlParameter.Value.ToString();
   parameter2=sqlParameter1.Value.ToString();

   return(parameter1,parameter2);
 }
```

and then get the values from tuple by the variable names like this

```
 var tuple=stAnswer(idFirst,idSecond);
 var val1=tuple.parameter1;
 var val2=tuple.parameter2;
```

Comment: That's the `Tuple` class that's been around longer than C# 7.  The value tuple added in C# 7 would be used like this `public (string, string) ...` and `return (sqlParameter.Value.ToString(), sqlParameter1.Value.ToString());`

Comment: Its been a while I used it in my project probably it was named tuple that was included in C#7.

Comment: I tried that before, but i have problems when i going to call the function

Comment: for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples

Answer (score 0):

C# has "out" parameters which can be used to return multiple values. See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier